# How to resize an ImageView in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to do something similar to the image below in Android. The problem is, whenever the screen size changes (when the user rotates the device), the checkboxes and the button disappear from the screen. This is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/preview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
android:layout_height= "1.5in" />

<CheckBox
android:id="@+id/location"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/preview"
android:text="@string/location_text" />

<CheckBox
android:id="@+id/timestamp"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/location"
android:text="@string/timestamp_text" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/buttonUpload"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/timestamp"
android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:onClick="uploadClicked"
android:text="@string/upload_button_text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I need to display the image and all controls and support all screen sizes. How do I make the size of the `ImageView` dynamic?

[image: shot]

Answer (score 5):

I never got the scaleType thing to work for me.

I subclassed ImageView:

```
package your.pkg;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class AspectRatioImageView extends ImageView {

  public AspectRatioImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  public AspectRatioImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  public AspectRatioImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
  if (getDrawable() != null && getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth() != 0) {
    int height = width * getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight() / getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
  } else {
    setMeasuredDimension(0, 0);
  }

 }
}
```

And used that instead of the regular ImageView:

```
<your.pkg.AspectRatioImageView
            android:id="@+id/photo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
/>
```

This scales to the full width of the parent View and maintains the aspect ratio while doing so.

Comment: I am not sure if this will solve my problem. I want to ensure that the checkboxes and buttons are visible when the screen size changes, it's okay for me if the image is smaller. Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: I misread your question. Sorry! I will delete my answer soon. Don't know what happens to your comment then.

Comment: I would put everything inside a ScrollView then. So the user can reach the button by scrolling down. But this might not be what you want.

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted, but does serve the purpose for now.

Answer (score 1):

If you used a `LinearLayout` instead of a `RelativeLayout`, you could make the `ImageView` expand to take all the empty space in the screen. The `scaleType` attribute will let you specify how to stretch the image.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/preview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

<CheckBox
android:id="@+id/location"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/location_text" />

<CheckBox
android:id="@+id/timestamp"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/timestamp_text" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/buttonUpload"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:onClick="uploadClicked"
android:text="@string/upload_button_text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I added a `android:orientation="vertical"` to your code and that fixed the orientation problem. But now, the image is not displayed in the image view and `logcat` does not show any errors. Any idea why changing the layout might cause this?

Comment: @Abhishek Chanda: Not really... you could try fiddling with `scaleType` to see if that has something to do with it. Or add a red background to the `ImageView` to make sure its size is what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

Based on all the feedback. This is what I used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroller"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/preview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
android:layout_height= "1.5in" />

<CheckBox
android:id="@+id/location"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/preview"
android:text="@string/location_text" />

<CheckBox
android:id="@+id/timestamp"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/location"
android:text="@string/timestamp_text" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/buttonUpload"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/timestamp"
android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:onClick="uploadClicked"
android:text="@string/upload_button_text" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```